# CSS inherits transparent from nowhere

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, transparent

Basically this CSS rule:

```
background:url('../img/logo-small.png');
```

On any browser, translates into:

```
background: url("../img/logo-small.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

I don't have any container that has a transparent rule, but apparently this prevents the background to be displayed. Strangely, `background-color` works instead.

If it's of any use, the content that appies to the CSS class is dynamically created with jQuery.

Is there a way to override this `transparent` parameter?

Comment: There is no inheritance going on; that is how shorthand properties work in CSS — any properties you didn't set will be implicitly set to their initial values (naturally, the initial value of `background-color` is `transparent`). This is why one should be careful when using shorthands.

Comment: well I thought it was strange because when I set the rule for other classes, it was working. But now that you make me think about abut, all of them had a background-color set!! thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `transparent` refers to the background color of the element, which is transparent by default. You can override this by explicitly setting a color, e.g.:

`background:url('../img/logo-small.png') #FFFFFF;`

Comment: yup don't worry. just need the 10 minutes to padd.